# is it possible in backbone model to have two index since server gives me messages with different id

Tags: backbone.js

in my application scenario of bus station, where each bus station has two way to identify it, its unique name,just like the normal name and unique public id number. As the client is interacting with the server side message, it will receive two different messages, first message use bus name to identity the station whereas the 2ed message uses the unique id number to identify the bus station.

So when designing the model for the bus stations, is it possible in a model to have two index, so no matter Num 1 or num 2 message I receive, the model could immediately help me find the model rather than looping over to find the station.

best rgards to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to achieve this, but it's quite simple to build a secondary index for a collection. Assuming that the name of a model never changes (which it shouldn't, since it's an unique identifier):

```
var StationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('add',    this._onAdd,    this);
    this.on('remove', this._onRemove, this);
    this.on('reset',  this._onReset,  this);
    this._onReset();
  },

  getByName: function(name) {
    return this._byName[name];
  },

  _onAdd: function(model) {
    this._byName[model.get('name')] = model;
  },

  _onRemove: function(model) {
    delete this._byName[model.get('name')];
  },

  _onReset: function(model) {
    this._byName = {};
    this.each(this._onAdd);
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
var station = stations.getByName('name_of_station');
```

/Code samples not tested